# React Navigation re-render previous page when going back

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

Whats the best way to refresh the previous page when going back using Stack Navigator. No life cycle hooks seems to be triggered on the page i am returning to. I'm just using the basic example and `this.props.navigation.goBack()`

Comment: Have you changed any state/props of the previous page before you go back? If you have changed, the previous page should re-render automatically.

Comment: Its a local database value that is getting changed that has an effect on the previous page. So i need it to check for any values changing in the database.

Answer (score 18):

You can use `addListener` for this

```js
componentDidMount() {

    this.props.navigation.addListener(
      'didFocus',
      payload => {
        this.forceUpdate();
      }
    );

}
```

Comment: In the latest RN release listen to the 'focus' event instead of 'didFocus'
https://reactnavigation.org/docs/function-after-focusing-screen

Answer (score 6):

in react functional component you can do like this:

```
const SomeComponent = (props) => {

useEffect(() => {
        props.navigation.addListener(
            'didFocus',
            payload => {
                //call some action here
            }
        );
    }, [])
}
```

Whenever you land on the component the above effect will fire, it will work whenever you are returning back from a navigation stack and you would like to fire an api or do some computations.

Answer (score 1):

Ok i have found the answer on reddit .https://www.reddit.com/r/reactnative/comments/69xm4p/react_navigation_tab_change_event/

I got it working using hooonkos onNavigationStateChange method ill paste the example he created below. I did not come up with this solution all credit should go to hooonko.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {
  AppRegistry,
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  View
} from 'react-native';
import { TabNavigator } from 'react-navigation';
import Icon from 'react-native-vector-icons/FontAwesome';


class MyHomeScreen extends React.Component {
  static navigationOptions = {
    tabBarLabel: 'Home',
    // Note: By default the icon is only shown on iOS. Search the showIcon option below.
    tabBarIcon: ({ tintColor }) => (
      <Icon
        name="home"
        size={30}
        color={tintColor}
      />
    ),
  };

  _myHomeFunction = () => {
    alert('Here is home tab!');
  }

  componentWillReceiveProps(newProps) {
    if (newProps.screenProps.route_index === 0) {
      this._myHomeFunction();
    }
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <Text style={styles.text}>
          Home
        </Text>
      </View>
    );
  }
}

class MyRocketScreen extends React.Component {
  static navigationOptions = {
    tabBarLabel: 'Rocket',
    tabBarIcon: ({ tintColor }) => (
      <Icon
        name="rocket"
        size={30}
        color={tintColor}
      />
    ),
  };

  _myRocketFunction = () => {
    alert('Here is rocket tab!');
  }

  componentWillReceiveProps(newProps) {
    if (newProps.screenProps.route_index === 1) {
      this._myRocketFunction();
    }
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <Text style={styles.text}>
          Rocket
        </Text>
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const MyApp = TabNavigator({
  Home: {
    screen: MyHomeScreen,
  },
  Rocket: {
    screen: MyRocketScreen,
  },
}, {
  tabBarOptions: {
    activeTintColor: '#e91e63',
  },
});

class rn extends Component {
  _onNavigationStateChange = (prevState, newState) => {
    this.setState({...this.state, route_index: newState.index});
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <MyApp onNavigationStateChange={this._onNavigationStateChange} screenProps={this.state} />
    )
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
    backgroundColor: '#F5FCFF',
  },
  text: {
    fontSize: 20,
    textAlign: 'center',
    margin: 10,
  },
});

AppRegistry.registerComponent('rn', () => rn);
```

Comment: `componentWillReceiveProps` has been deprecated.

Comment: @cmcodes Yup should use getDerivedStateFromProps from now on

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```
const SomeComponent = (props) => {

    useEffect(() => {
        props.navigation.addListener(
            'focus',
            payload => {
                // call some action here
            }
        );
    }, [])

}
```

It will execute whenever navigation is focusing on component.

For a class component this should work:

```
componentDidMount() {

  this.props.navigation.addListener(
    'focus',
    payload => {
      // call some action here
    }
  );

}
```